# Intellij regex to find and replace

Tags: intellij-idea

I need below text to be find by using regex in Intellij

```
messageSource.getMessage("error1.test1",null, null)
messageSource.getMessage("error2.test2",null, null)
messageSource.getMessage("error3.test3",null, null)
messageSource.getMessage("error4.test4",null, null)
messageSource.getMessage("success",null, null)
messageSource.getMessage("error",null, null)
```

I need this to replace with below

```
messageSource.getMessage("error1.test1",null, Locale.ENGLISH)
messageSource.getMessage("error2.test2",null, Locale.ENGLISH)
messageSource.getMessage("error3.test3",null, Locale.ENGLISH)
messageSource.getMessage("error4.test4",null, Locale.ENGLISH)
messageSource.getMessage("success",null, Locale.ENGLISH)
messageSource.getMessage("error",null, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Note: These are just some examples, but hundres of lines are there across the project. `error1.test1`, `success` these texts can be with `.` (dot) or without dot , no `numerics` involved (only alphabets)

I tired to some extend, but couldn't finish exactly
`messageSource.getMessage\(\"[a-zA-Z]*.[a-zA-Z]*",[null]*,[null]*`

Comment: Why not `null)` -> `Locale.ENGLISH)`?

Comment: I'm fixing sonar issues, since Locale is not `@nullable`, Im getting warning message from Sonar,

Comment: I mean, replace `null)` with `Locale.ENGLISH)` seems solving your issue, and it's obvious.

Comment: There are multiple other place we have `null)`, so it will get affect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    messageSource.getMessage\(\s*(\S+?)\s*,\s*null\s*,\s*null\s*\)
Replace: messageSource.getMessage($1, null, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Comment: Oh man, Thats awesome. Im interested know about `$1`, `\S+?` everything ( i will check by myself) Thanks!

Comment: `\S+` means match one or more non whitespace characters, and `$1` refers to the first (and only) capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Structural Search & Replace would work well here (`Edit | Find | Replace Structurally`).
Example template for your use case:

```
<replaceConfiguration name="stackoverflow" text="messageSource.getMessage(&quot;$text$&quot;,null, null)" recursive="false" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" search_injected="false" reformatAccordingToStyle="false" shortenFQN="false" replacement="messageSource.getMessage(&quot;$text$&quot;,null, java.util.Locale.ENGLISH)" case_sensitive="true">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="text" within="" contains="" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

Use the `Import Template from Clipboard` action in the dialog.